# Another Way to Write Ternary Operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-operator

Is this logical operation:

```js
const user = users && users[0] || null;
```

the same as this conditional / ternary operation:

```js
const user = users ? users[0] : null;
```

? Assuming `users` is an array.

Comment: If `users` always is an array, it is always thruthy and testing for it is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not the same. If `users[0]` is falsey, the `|| null` will be selected in the first code:

```js
const users = [0];
const user1 = users && users[0] || null;
const user2 = users ? users[0] : null;

console.log(user1, user2);
```

The conditional operator is probably the better choice. But, even better, in modern JavaScript, you can use optional chaining instead, which is even more concise:

```js
let users;

const user = users?.[0];
console.log(user);
```

(though, note that it gives you `undefined` if the nested property doesn't exist, not `null`)

Comment: Ah interesting, I didn't know about the optional chaining. It's like a safe call in Kotlin.

Answer (score -1):

Using `users` on its own isn't a very good way to do tests. Some languages like Go only allow tests against boolean values. To that end, it would be better to test against a boolean value if possible. Something like:

```
const user = users.length > 0 ? users[0] : null;
```